# View topics I've flagged

Tags: support

Is there a way to view topics I've flagged?  I want to know if my flags have been acted on or not, in order to get a sense of where the community's comfort levels are for things that are borderline against the rules or off topic.

Comment: No need to put "solved" in the title. Just click the check mark next to the voting arrows in the answer that solved your problem. That'll automatically mark that answer as the accepted answer, and mark your post as solved!

Comment: Thanks @nhinkle, I've done so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your profile, click on the `helpful flags` count to see all the flags you've raised.

[image: example profile]

Comment: For you @ChimneyImp that would be http://superuser.com/users/flag-summary/129390

Comment: Derp, I can't believe I didn't think of that.  Thanks.

Comment: oliver or @iglvzx... where'd that screenshot come from? Did you go all web-inspector-edit on Community or something?

Comment: @nhinkle That was me. If you see the revision comment, I was bored. :P

Comment: @iglvzx: That's awesome!